# Size of randomly drawn subgraph of strongly regular graph

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, graph-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider a strongly regular connected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $\bar{n}=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ vertices, each vertex has degree $2(n-2)$, two adjacent notes having $n-2$ common neighbors and any two non-adjacent notes having $4$ common neighbors. This is the also known as the Johnson graph $J(n,2)$.
Draw without replacement $k<\bar{n}$ vertices $\{V_1,...,V_k\}$ from $V$ and denote by $\mathcal{E}$ the size of the induced subgraph on $\{V_1,...,V_k\}$.
I want to deduce the distribution of $\mathcal{E}$ as a function of $k$ and $n$ but I am a bit lost.

I tried to come up with a recursive discription of the drawing process starting from picking one $v_1\in V$. The second one is with probability $\dfrac{4(n-2)}{n(n-1)}$ a neighbor of $v_1$ such that we add $1$ to $\mathcal{E}$. With probability $1-\dfrac{4(n-2)}{n(n-1)}$ the value of $\mathcal{E}$ remains $0$. I would continue for the cases $3$ but this blows up rapidely. Does anyone have a more efficient and insightful approach?

Comment: "Deduce the distribution" is a very tall order. Computing the expected value or the variance is probably doable, but the distribution isn't likely to be anything nice...

Comment: And finding the range of $\mathcal{E}$? Could that be a feasible task?

Comment: It doesn't seem immediately obvious to me what it would be, but it sounds doable in principle. I wouldn't think of that as a probability problem; we are simpliy looking for the most and least dense $k$-vertex subgraphs of $J(n,2)$. (And second, for any gaps in the possible values, if you are interested in that.)

Comment: Thank you for this perspective on the problem. Can you recommend an approach on how to find these or literature read up on this task? Its completely unkown to me.

Comment: I'd try to ask a computer to look at small and medium-size examples to figure out what you should be proving. Conjecturally, the densest subgraphs of $J(n,2)$ will probably be copies of $J(n',2)$ for $n' < n$...

Comment: Since I am not interested in the complete structure but only the size in terms of edges of the densest /least dense subgraph I am wondering whether it is really necessary to calculate the whole subgraph or whether there is a way to find just its size.